# Batch rename of .7k files

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, batch-processing, file-rename

I want to rename files using the command prompt with a prefix of 'g_x_'.  The structure of the original file names are:

000_1565.7k

I have tried:

```
ren *.7k g_x_*.7k
```

That code will rename the files to 'g_x_1565.7k', but i really need the files to be named 'g_x_000_1565.7k'

Any ideas on why the code is dropping part of the original file name?

Thanks,

DH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d *_*.7k ^|findstr /v /b /l "g_x_" '
 ) DO (
  REN "%%a" "g_x_%%a"   
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The `dir` finds filenames that match `*_*.7k` and this is piped to a `FINDSTR` which allows through only those names that do NOT match (`/v`) the literal (`/l`) string `"g_x_"` at the beginning (`/b`). The caret (`^`) before the pipe is required to tell CMD that the pipe is part of the command to be executed by the `for`, not a parameter to the `dir`.

The resultant filenames are then assigned to `%%a`, prepended and renamed

This approach first makes a list of the existing filenames, then processes that list. If an attempt is made to rename in-place, then it's possible that a file aaa_bbb.7k would be renamed to g_x_aaa_bbb.7k and then again to g_x_g_x_aaa_bbb.7k...

Answer (score 0):

Store the filename of each file in a variable and prefix it with 'g_x_' + variable name.

*If all your files begin with 000_** then use the following on the **command line**:

`FOR %? IN (000_*.7k) DO ren %? g_x_%?`

in the batch file, use:

`FOR %%? IN (000_*.7k) DO ren %? g_x_%%?`

Comment: can you explain a little more?

Comment: Updated answer. Simpler than I thought. Let me know if you need any further help on this.

Comment: This will process some files twice.

Comment: @foxidrive, kindly elaborate.

Comment: A simple `for in do` progressively gathers files of the filespec and processes them all. If you rename the filespec then it will process some files twice, as it thinks they are new files. It's a bug, and a solution is to use `FOR /F` with a `DIR` as that creates a list of all files before starting.  **On further reflection it may be that the filespec will no longer match and so it will not be an issue.**

Comment: @foxidrive Thanks for the elaborate comment! I'd realized the multiple renaming issue in one of my tests. Thus I specifically searched on '000_*.7k' instead of '*.7k' | I believe this should make an elegant solution, given the constraints | Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of @PeterWright solution but it allows you to add `/s` in the `DIR` switches to process subdirectories too, if you need to do that.

As it stands it will only echo the rename commands to the screen - so remove the `echo` to enable the rename if you like what you see on the screen.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (' dir /b /a-d *_*.7k ') DO (
 echo REN "%%a" "g_x_%%~nxa"   
)
pause
```